# Python Selenium find_element_by_name skip to 2nd element

Tags: python, selenium

I have some code which works well.

```
driver.find_element_by_name(
            'StatusCode').get_attribute('innerText') == 'Available'
```

But there's 2 elements with the name StatusCode and it's selecting the first and I need the second one. Is there a way to skip the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all the elements on a page, you can use the `find_elements_by_x` version of the driver's `find_element_by_x` functions. These versions return a list of elements instead of a single element so you'll need to modify your logic accordingly.

- `find_element_by_name` => `find_elements_by_name`
- `find_element_by_xpath` => `find_elements_by_xpath`
- `find_element_by_link_text` => `find_elements_by_link_text`
- `find_element_by_partial_link_text` => `find_elements_by_partial_link_text`
- `find_element_by_tag_name` => `find_elements_by_tag_name`
- `find_element_by_class_name` => `find_elements_by_class_name`
- `find_element_by_css_selector` => `find_elements_by_css_selector`

```py
driver.find_elements_by_name('StatusCode')[1].get_attribute('innerText') == 'Available'
```